# How to understand the proof of the division theorem in the four arithmetic operation theorems of probability convergence for random variables?

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, proof-explanation, law-of-large-numbers

\begin{equation}
Y_n \stackrel{P}{\longrightarrow} b \text {}
\end{equation}
and:
\begin{aligned}
& P\left(\left|\frac{1}{Y_n}-\frac{1}{b}\right| \geqslant \varepsilon\right)=P\left(\left|\frac{Y_n-b}{Y_n b}\right| \geqslant \varepsilon\right) \\
= & P\left(\left|\frac{Y_n-b}{b^2+b\left(Y_n-b\right)}\right| \geqslant \varepsilon,\left|Y_n-b\right|<\varepsilon\right)+P\left(\left|\frac{Y_n-b}{b^2+b\left(Y_n-b\right)}\right| \geqslant \varepsilon,\left|Y_n-b\right| \geqslant \varepsilon\right) \\
\leqslant & P\left(\frac{\left|Y_n-b\right|}{b^2-\varepsilon|b|} \geqslant \varepsilon\right)+P\left(\left|Y_n-b\right| \geqslant \varepsilon\right)=P\left(\left|Y_n-b\right| \geqslant\left(b^2-\varepsilon|b|\right) \varepsilon\right)+P\left(\left|Y_n-b\right| \geqslant \varepsilon\right) \rightarrow 0(n \rightarrow \infty) .
\end{aligned}
so
\begin{equation}
1 / Y_n \stackrel{P}{\longrightarrow} 1 / b
\end{equation}
my question is how to understand this step:
$$
P\left(\left|\frac{Y_n-b}{b^2+b\left(Y_n-b\right)}\right| \geqslant \varepsilon,\left|Y_n-b\right|<\varepsilon\right) \leq P\left(\frac{\left|Y_n-b\right|}{b^2-\varepsilon|b|} \geqslant \varepsilon\right)
$$
i cannot figure it out.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality take $\epsilon <|b|$.

$|b^{2}+b(Y_n-b)|\geq b^{2}-|b(Y_n-b)| \ge  b^{2}-\epsilon |b|$ if $|Y_n-b| <\epsilon$. Hence, $\epsilon \le|\frac{Y_n-b}{b^2+b(Y_n-b)}|\le \frac {|Y_n-b|} {b^{2}-\epsilon |b|}$

Comment: Thank you!And another question is ,what if "b^2-epsilon|b|" is negative?Actually that's my real question.Then the right side of your inequation may be wrong?

Comment: @SUNi For proving convergence in probability it is enough to take $0<\epsilon<|b|$.